# Finding the View location (position) on display (screen) in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I want to find the view's position on the display screen.

To do it, I use the methods such as `view.getLeft()` ,`view.getBottom()` , `view.getRight()` , `view.getTop()`. But unfortunately, all these methods are returned `0`.
Is there any alternate way to find the view's positions (i.e coordinates on screen)?

My layout `main.xml`:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="200px"
    android:layout_height="30px"
    android:text="welcome to" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/tv2"
    android:layout_width="200px"
    android:layout_height="30px"
    android:text=" Make Eit solution " />
```

And my class has this in `onCreate()`:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);

System.out.println("tv4 width:"+tv2.getWidth());
System.out.println("tv4 height:"+tv2.getHeight());
System.out.println("Right:"+tv2.getRight());
System.out.println("Left:"+tv2.getLeft());
System.out.println("Top:"+tv2.getTop());
System.out.println("Bottom:"+tv2.getBottom());
```

Comment: Here I have founded the answer. [Get coordinates of View][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224844/how-to-get-the-absolute-coordinates-of-a-view

Answer (score 9):

Easiest way is to get it using 
`View.getLocationOnScreen();`  OR   `getLocationInWindow();`

And if you **want position relative to root Layou**t then [**See**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3621042/3496570)

Answer (score 6):

Use the `getLeft()`, `getRight()`, `getTop()`, and `getBottom()`. These can be used after the view is instantiated.

Comment: These methods give the view position **relative to** its parent.

Comment: @ilkinulas so what is the solution for the relative to the device ?

Answer (score 6):

the methods u have written is enough to
find the location on screen, but the place where you have written is not correct.

try to write the methods (view.getLeft(), view.getTop()... etc) in **onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)** method.

for example...

**

```
@Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus) {
                System.out.println("Right:"+tv2.getRight());
                System.out.println("Left:"+tv2.getLeft());
                System.out.println("Top:"+tv2.getTop());
        }
    }
```

**

it will solve your issue.

Comment: This is the perfect answer to this question.+1

Answer (score 3):

You really can't get the view before hand. You may want to do an explicit using `invalidate()` if possible or you can check this in the `onPostResume()` or `onResume()` function.

If you're just trying things out and want to have fun with threads, this code block will put your code onto the UI thread and will wait for everything to be rendered and then display your code:

```
final View gv = this;
ViewTreeObserver vto = gv.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        gv.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

        tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        System.out.println("tv4 width:"+tv2.getWidth());
        System.out.println("tv4 height:"+tv2.getHeight());
        System.out.println("Right:"+tv2.getRight());
        System.out.println("Left:"+tv2.getLeft());
        System.out.println("Top:"+tv2.getTop());
        System.out.println("Bottom:"+tv2.getBottom());
}
```

This last one is pretty heavy duty lifting but it will get the job done. I usually put any lines like this in my logs(i.e. `android.util.Log`)

Comment: `getLeft()`, `getRight()` won't work every time as they return the position relative to the parent, not the screen.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that you can get the position of the view before the layout phase have been done. Once the view is layed out you can use `getLocationOnScreen` to get the position of the view. `getTop` and similar only returns the position of the view in its parent.