# Add tooltip arrow to DialogFragment

Tags: android, dialog, tooltip

I am trying to use `DialogFragment` as tooltip with a tooltip arrow pointing to its source button.

I can position the `DialogFragment` with the help of the following link.
[Position of DialogFragment in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698410/position-of-dialogfragment-in-android)

But I can not find any help in adding a tooltip arrow to the `DialogFragment`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many open source libraries and codes available to find out how it can be developed.

1. https://github.com/nhaarman/supertooltips
2. https://github.com/nidhinek/android-tooltip
3. https://github.com/douglasjunior/android-simple-tooltip
4. https://github.com/michaelye/EasyDialog

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to look into this library:
[skydoves-Balloon](https://github.com/skydoves/Balloon)

this one has clear documentation