# how to use fragments to create an overlay effect for an add contact function when a button is pressed

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, user-interface

I'm trying to create an overlay that is triggered when a button is pressed. This overlay is supposed to allow the user to add their contact and I was wondering how can I use fragments to get this effect like you can see in this mockup.[image: Adobe XD Mockup]
I am in a dilemna over using fragments is the right choice. My reasoning being that I only need to have it do one task that is adding contacts, and thus I do not need a whole activity.

This is what I have on the main activity right now[image: Main Activity Java File]
[image: Main Activity xml File]

I would really appreciate any help on understanding how to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `DialogFragment`.
It behaves like a normal `Fragment` for the most part. Here is a guide for a basic implementation https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-dialogfragment

They appear automatically in the center of the screen. To get it a bit lower like in your mockup you can change where it is in the window. Here is an answer showing such [Position of DialogFragment in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698410/position-of-dialogfragment-in-android)

Comment: Ah I see ! 
Thank you so much
I was concerned whether dialog box only handles basic text and image popups but It seems I was incorrect.
Thank you for the tip !