# TextInputLayout.setError() leaves empty space after clearing the error

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I recently used `TextInputLayout` and it's `setError()` method. The problem I'm getting is, when I clear the error by calling `setError(null)` it leaves so much of empty space at the bottom.

*Normal:*

[image: Normal]

*With error:*

[image: With error]

*After clearing error:*

[image: After clearing error]

After looking at the source, I found that they are making the view `INVISIBLE` instead of `GONE`

> ```
> .setListener(new ViewPropertyAnimatorListenerAdapter() {
> @Override
> public void onAnimationEnd(View view) {
>     view.setVisibility(INVISIBLE); // here it is
>
>     updateLabelVisibility(true);
> } }).start();
> ```

I'm wondering why is it so? How to resolve this to avoid the empty space?

Comment: Actually are you giving your own animation for it?

Answer (score 170, accepted):

Check out the docs for

```
public void setErrorEnabled (boolean enabled)
```

It says

> Whether the error functionality is enabled or not in this layout.
>   Enabling this functionality before setting an error message via
>   setError(CharSequence), will mean that this layout will not change
>   size when an error is displayed.

Well based on this, try setting `setErrorEnabled(true)` before `setError()`, and, set `setErrorEnabled(false)` after `setError(null)`.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for pointing this out. But still it occupies a lot of space and also it is not predictable while previewing the layout. I still don't understand why they made it so.

Comment: well not really sure why they implemented this way, yes having View.GONE would be better to save space but could have created problems for some complex view groups if they were underneath TextInputLayout and they would have to shift down.

Comment: on seterror it expands. but setting error to null or settingErrorEnabled to false does not collapse back the layout.

Comment: setError calls setErrorEnabled(true) internally

Comment: Excelent! I created two extension functions for this: fun TextInputLayout.showError(errorText: String) {
    this.isErrorEnabled = true
    this.error = errorText
}

fun TextInputLayout.removeError() {
    this.isErrorEnabled = false
    this.error = null
}

Answer (score 55):

Method `setErrorEnabled(false)` will clear the extra space, so call it after `setError(null)`.

Comment: This response gives me the result I was expecting. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I needed!

Comment: Why do we need `setError(null)`?

Answer (score 6):

Dont use `setErrorEnabled(boolean)`, it just doesnt show up the error from the second time.

```
public class MyTextInputLayout extends android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout {

public MyTextInputLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MyTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MyTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
public void setError(@Nullable CharSequence error) {
    super.setError(error);

    View layout = getChildAt(1);
    if (layout != null) {
        if (error != null && !"".equals(error.toString().trim())) {
            layout.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        } else {
            layout.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Then just `setError(errorMessage);` or `setError(null);`

Comment: Works fine, but it promptly deletes the text. Is there a way to animate it?

Answer (score 4):

See [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=194030) page. Google will release the fix in future support library version. It says,

> If you want to fix it now you can extends the `TextInputLayout` and
>   override the `setErrorEnabled()` method, but I cant guarantee the
>   backward compatibility. Because its some danger to change state in
>   `TextInputLayout`.
>
> ```
> public class TextInputLayout extends android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout{
>
>
>     public TextInputLayout(Context context) {
>         super(context);
>     }
>
>     public TextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
>         super(context, attrs);
>     }
>
>     public TextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
>         super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void setErrorEnabled(boolean enabled) {
>         super.setErrorEnabled(enabled);
>         if (enabled) {
>             return;
>         }
>         if (getChildCount() > 1) {
>             View view = getChildAt(1);
>             if (view != null) {
>                 view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: @HRaval the bug has fixed in support library v23.2.0, but I have not verify it

Comment: @ShaodeLu, I have checked 23.3.0, they didn't fix it

Answer (score 4):

I create a custom view for avoiding repeated code and override `setError` method.

```
    public class UserInputView extends TextInputLayout {

        public UserInputView(Context context) {
           this(context, null);
        }

        public UserInputView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            this(context, attrs, 0);
        }

        public UserInputView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        }

        @Override
        public void setError(@Nullable CharSequence error) {
            boolean isErrorEnabled = error != null;
            setErrorEnabled(isErrorEnabled);
            super.setError(error);
        }

     }
```

Answer (score 4):

The source code of TextInputLayout show the following:
If you need to clear the error, just use

```
til.setErrorEnabled(false);
```

This will hide the error text and stretch the bottom space to its standard size.

In case you need to set the error again, just use

```
til.setError("Your text");
```

which automatically calls `til.setErrorEnabled(true)` as it assumes you need the error functionality.

Answer (score 4):

This is extension in kotlin solving problem:

```
fun TextInputLayout.clearError() {
    error = null
    isErrorEnabled = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The following code works fine**

```
    textInputLatout.getEditText().addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.length() < 1) {
               textInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);
                textInputLayout.setError("Please enter a value");
            }

            if (s.length() > 0) {
                textInputLayout.setError(null);
                textInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `mTextInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);` i have solved this problem

Answer (score -3):

Then you should override it like so:

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(View view)
{
    view.setVisibility(GONE); // <-- this is where you make it GONE

    updateLabelVisibility(true); 
}
```

Or try this i.e. on a button or whatever you are using:

```
final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
btn.setVisibility(View.GONE); //<--- makes the button gone
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm not getting what are you saying.

Comment: A view can be anything like a button for example.