# textinputlayout errorenabled and showing errors

Tags: android, textinputlayout

So I have login form, when user click login I will check the inputs.

First what I do, onlick of login button i call `textinputlayout.seterrorenabled(false)`, then when API call is over and I have an error on my editttext i call `textinputlayout.seterrorenabled(true)`, `textinputlayout.seterror(message)`. Everything is all good, now I click on login again and repeat same process `textinputlayout.seterrorenabled(false)` and then after API call is over `textinputlayout.seterrorenabled(true)`, `textinputlayout.seterror(message)`. However this time the message doesn't show up. What's the problem?

```
          <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/usernameField1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/usernameField"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/user_name"
                    android:textColorHint="#808080"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/tendp"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/tendp"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/tendp"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/tendp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textSize" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/passwordField1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/passwordField"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/password"
                    android:textColorHint="#808080"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/tendp"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/tendp"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/tendp"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/tendp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textSize" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/login"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:text="@string/login"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textSize" >
                </Button>



  final Button login =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    //  login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        login.setOnClickListener(here i set my textinputlayout to errorenabled false or seterror null // start an asynctask 



  here in asynctask onpostexecute i set the errorenabled(true) and set error( the message)
```

Comment: please post some code here.

Comment: could be an issue of milliseconds. i call seterror("message1") then directly seterror("message2")..its taking message 1 and not message 2.

Comment: yes could be bug in android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34242902/textinputlayout-seterror-leaves-empty-space-after-clearing-the-error my issue is having lot of space when its verified correct.  another issue  is error not being displayed after being verified and edited to wrong choice.

Answer (score -1):

Do not use `textinputlayout.seterrorenabled(true)` or  `textinputlayout.seterrorenabled(true)` just `textinputlayout.seterror(message)` if you want to display message  or `textinputlayout.seterror(null)` if you dont

Comment: doesnt work, first time it shows. second time it doesnt.

Comment: could be an issue of milliseconds. i call seterror("message1") then directly seterror("message2")..its taking message 1 and not message 2.

Comment: btw try after setting seterror(null), to seterror("fail") and see if it works.

Comment: yes could be bug in android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34242902/textinputlayout-seterror-leaves-empty-space-after-clearing-the-error my issue is having lot of space when its verified correct.  another issue  is error not being displayed after being verified and edited to wrong choice.