# What is the android equivalent of UIView's convertRect / convertPoint functions?

Tags: android, coordinate-transformation

UIView has the following:

```
- convertPoint:toView:
- convertPoint:fromView:
- convertRect:toView:
- convertRect:fromView:
```

What is the Android equivalent?  More generally, given two `View`s, how do I get the second `View`'s rect in the coordinate system of the first?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't think there is an equivalent as part of the sdk, but it seems like you could write your own implementation very easily using `getLocationOnScreen`:

```
public static Point convertPoint(Point fromPoint, View fromView, View toView){
    int[] fromCoord = new int[2];
    int[] toCoord = new int[2];
    fromView.getLocationOnScreen(fromCoord);
    toView.getLocationOnScreen(toCoord);

    Point toPoint = new Point(fromCoord[0] - toCoord[0] + fromPoint.x,
            fromCoord[1] - toCoord[1] + fromPoint.y);

    return toPoint;
}
```

---

```
public static Rect convertRect(Rect fromRect, View fromView, View toView){
    int[] fromCoord = new int[2];
    int[] toCoord = new int[2];
    fromView.getLocationOnScreen(fromCoord);
    toView.getLocationOnScreen(toCoord);

    int xShift = fromCoord[0] - toCoord[0];
    int yShift = fromCoord[1] - toCoord[1];

    Rect toRect = new Rect(fromRect.left + xShift, fromRect.top + yShift,
            fromRect.right + xShift, fromRect.bottom + yShift);

    return toRect;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android it might not have the method that exactly like that

however, you could do by

`View.getLocationOnScreen(int[] location)` and `View.getLocationInWindowint[] location()`

which

> **getLocationOnScreen(int[] location)**
>
> Computes the coordinates of this view in
>   its window.
>
> **getLocationInWindow(int[] location)**
>
> Computes the coordinates of this view on
>   the screen.

---

or View.getLeft() and View.getTop()

which

> **getLeft()**
>
> Left position of this view relative to its parent.
>
> **getTop()**
>
> Top position of this view relative to its parent.

---

for you case, I would use getLeft() and getTop() to find it's space between 2 View and get range of it

this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619693/getting-views-coordinates-relative-to-the-root-layout) has an example of how to find it using getLeft() and getTop()

```
private int getRelativeLeft(View myView) {
    if (myView.getParent() == myView.getRootView())
        return myView.getLeft();
    else
        return myView.getLeft() + getRelativeLeft((View) myView.getParent());
}

private int getRelativeTop(View myView) {
    if (myView.getParent() == myView.getRootView())
        return myView.getTop();
    else
        return myView.getTop() + getRelativeTop((View) myView.getParent());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is with [getGlobalVisibleRect(Rect r, Point globalOffset)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getGlobalVisibleRect%28android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Point%29).

```
/**
 * If some part of this view is not clipped by any of its parents, then
 * return that area in r in global (root) coordinates. To convert r to local
 * coordinates (without taking possible View rotations into account), offset
 * it by -globalOffset (e.g. r.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y)).
 * If the view is completely clipped or translated out, return false.
 *
 * @param r If true is returned, r holds the global coordinates of the
 *        visible portion of this view.
 * @param globalOffset If true is returned, globalOffset holds the dx,dy
 *        between this view and its root. globalOffet may be null.
 * @return true if r is non-empty (i.e. part of the view is visible at the
 *         root level.
 */
```

So you give it a `Point` and get the offset relative to the root `View`. They key is that your views get a location relative to a common item. You can then use this offset to calculate relative positions. The doc says to get local coordinates, you offset the `Rect` with -globalOffset. If you want to get the second view's `Rect` in coordinates of the first, then offset the `Rect` of the *first* view with -globalOffset of the *second* view.

Similarly, you can use the `globalOffset` to transform a point to relative coordinates if you know it's coordinates in the root view. This should be a subtraction: `anyPoint - globalOffset`.

Remember to check that `getGlobalVisibleRect()` returned true and that `globalOffset` is not null before you do the calculations.