# How to get coordinates of view in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I'm trying to animate a view movement in RelativeLayout with respect to others views' position.

So my layout looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>
     <View alignParentLeft>
     <View centerHorizontal>
     <View alignParentRight>
     <AnimatedView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I use *ObjectAnimator* to animate this view:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(animatedView, "x", animatedView.getX(), childView.getX());
```

But all child views except the one I'm trying to animate, returns 0 for *getX()* or *getLeft()*.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619693/getting-views-coordinates-relative-to-the-root-layout

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to the fact that when you're trying to start your `Animation` your `Views` don't have dimensions yet (have not been drawn yet). Are you trying to start your animation in something like `Activity's` `onCreate` or `Fragment's` `onCreateView`?

To make sure your `Views` are ready to be animated you can use for example this:

```
yourRelativeLayout.getViewTreeObserver()
                .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
       int width = yourRelativeLayout.getWidth();
       int height = yourRelativeLayout.getHeight();
        if (width > 0 && height > 0) {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
              yourRelativeLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
              yourRelativeLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }

            //START YOUR ANIMATION HERE
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: No, the animation starts by clicking on a button. I guess a layout measure it's dimension to that moment.

Comment: Post your complete layout, there's not enough information then.