# Smoothy scroll to Child in NestedScrollView

Tags: android, nestedscrollview

I have expandable views inside `CardView` thats parent is `NestedScrollView`. I'm trying to create smooth scroll to child when expand animation ended. But I found only one solution:

```
 scrollView.requestChildFocus(someView, someView);
```

This code works fine, but, when call `requestChildFocus` it scrolls immediately, and that annoying me a little bit. Is it possible to scroll to child smoothly?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html#smoothScrollTo(int, int)  ?

Comment: @Budius, if I'm not mistaken, there is no such method

Comment: I've passed the link to the official documentation, I'm pretty sure it exists as the documentation is auto-generated based on the code comments. Maybe you have to update to the latest support lib ?

Comment: You mean there is no such method like the one described in the original Android documentation?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The `childView`, to which I wanted to scroll, has `CardView` parrent, so `childView.getTop()` returns the value relative to the `CardView` not to the `ScrollView`. So, to get top relative to `ScrollView` I should get `childView.getParent().getParent()` then cast it to `View` and call `getTop()`.

Scroll position calculates like

```
int scrollTo = ((View) childView.getParent().getParent()).getTop() + childView.getTop();
nestedScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, scrollTo);
```

Comment: `nestedScrollView.smoothScrollTo` doesn't work at all for me (Support lib 27.1.1)

Answer (score 6):

more to the answer from @jerry-sha

```
fun NestedScrollView.smoothScrollTo(view: View) {
  var distance = view.top
  var viewParent = view.parent
  //traverses 10 times
  for (i in 0..9) {
    if ((viewParent as View) === this) break
    distance += (viewParent as View).top
    viewParent = viewParent.getParent()
  }
  smoothScrollTo(0, distance)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had child views at different levels to the scrollview so made this function based off the accepted answer to calculate the distance and scroll

```
  private int findDistanceToScroll(View view){
    int distance = view.getTop();
    ViewParent viewParent = view.getParent();
    //traverses 10 times
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (((View) viewParent).getId() == R.id.journal_scrollview) {
            return distance;
        }
        distance += ((View) viewParent).getTop();
        viewParent = viewParent.getParent();
    }
    Timber.w("view not found");
    return 0;
}
```

Then scroll using

```
journal_scrollview.smoothScrollTo(0, distance);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to read the source code.

```
svMain.setSmoothScrollingEnabled(true);
Rect rect = new Rect();
rect.top = 0;
rect.left = 0;
rect.right = tv4.getWidth();
rect.bottom =tv4.getHeight();
svMain.requestChildRectangleOnScreen(tv4,rect,false);
```

`rect` is the place u want the view to be shown on screen.

Comment: Get the CardView's position and try to scroll to the place

Comment: Dont works as I need. It scrolls now to about top fourth part of view size ((

Answer (score 1):

You can use my library [`ViewPropertyObjectAnimator`](https://github.com/blipinsk/ViewPropertyObjectAnimator) for that.

Assuming `mNestedScrollView` is your `NestedScrollView` and `mChildView` is the child `View` you want to scroll to, you can do the following:

```
ViewPropertyObjectAnimator.animate(mNestedScrollView).scrollY(mChildView.getTop()).start();
```

Just make sure `mChildView.getTop()` is not `0` at the moment of calling `.animate(...)`.

Edit:

As I said: make sure your `View's` top is non-zero when CALL `.animate(...)`. In other words: call `.animate(...)` only when your child `View` already has dimensions. How can you determine that? For example like this:

```
mChildView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
       int width = mChildView.getWidth();
       int height = mChildView.getHeight();
        if (width > 0 && height > 0) {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
              mChildView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
              mChildView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }

            ViewPropertyObjectAnimator.animate(mNestedScrollView)
                    .scrollY(mChildView.getTop())
                    .start();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: My child view's top is always 0 when animation ends (((

Comment: I cant check this answer now ( I'll do it tomorrow. Could You say me if '.scrollY()' is trying to place myChildView to top of screen or to first it's visible pixel?

Comment: `mChildView.getTop()` represents the number of pixels from the top of your `View` to the top of the `NestedScrollView` content. And this command will scroll your `NestedScrollView` exactly by this amount.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is to calculate the correct x/y position **relative** to the nestedscrollview. However, most of the answers here try to propose a solution by navigating in the hierarchy and hardcoding the hierarchy-level of the desired view. Imho, this is very error prone, if you change your viewgroup hierarchy.

Therefore, I would suggest to use a [much more cleaner approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36740277/3371707), which computes the relative position based on a `Rect`. Then, you can use the nestedscrollview's [smoothScrollTo(..)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/widget/NestedScrollView#smoothScrollTo(int,%20int,%20int)) methods to scroll to the desired position.

Answer (score 0):

This should get the work done, where childView is the view you want to scroll to

```
public static void scrollToView(final NestedScrollView nestedScrollView, final View viewToScrollTo) {
        final int[] xYPos = new int[2];
        viewToScrollTo.getLocationOnScreen(xYPos);
        final int[] scrollxYPos = new int[2];
        nestedScrollView.getLocationOnScreen(scrollxYPos);
        int yPosition = xYPos[1];
        if (yPosition < 0) {
            yPosition = 0;
        }
        nestedScrollView.scrollTo(0, scrollxYPos[1] - yPosition);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the accepted answer to work, but it is specific to their view structure as of now and it could not be used as a static method to use for all similar scrolls with different view structures. I made a variety of it in a utility class that measures until it find it's ScrollView or NestedScrollView parent. I made it so that the scrollToView(View,View) method should work with both ScrollView and NestedScrollView in case I would update which I use later on or whatever. You could of course call the right "child method" directly.

```
public static void scrollToView(View scrollView, View scrollToView) {
    if (scrollToView == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "scrollToView() failed due to scrollToView == NULL!");
        return;
    }
    if (scrollView instanceof NestedScrollView) {
        scrollToInNestedView((NestedScrollView) scrollView, scrollToView);
    } else if (scrollView instanceof ScrollView) {
        scrollToInScrollView((ScrollView) scrollView, scrollToView);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "scrollToView() failed due to scrollView not appearing to be any kind of scroll view!");
    }
}

public static void scrollToInNestedView(NestedScrollView scrollView, View scrollToView) {
    if (scrollView == null || scrollToView == null) {
        return;
    }
    scrollView.post(() -> {
        int startY = scrollView.getScrollY();
        int requiredY = scrollToView.getTop();
        View parent = (View) scrollToView.getParent();
        while (parent != null && !(parent instanceof NestedScrollView)) {
            requiredY += parent.getTop();
            parent = (View) parent.getParent();
        }
        if (requiredY != startY) {
            scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, requiredY);
        }
    });
}

public static void scrollToInScrollView(ScrollView scrollView, View scrollToView) {
    if (scrollView == null || scrollToView == null) {
        return;
    }
    scrollView.post(() -> {
        int startY = scrollView.getScrollY();
        int requiredY = scrollToView.getTop();
        View parent = (View) scrollToView.getParent();
        while (parent != null && !(parent instanceof ScrollView)) {
            requiredY += parent.getTop();
            parent = (View) parent.getParent();
        }
        if (requiredY != startY) {
            scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, requiredY);
        }
    });
}
```