# When do coordinates of child views become valid?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a `RelativeLayout` with lots of child views, and I want to calculate a position of one of them (relative to the parent container) once the activity is started.

My problem is that I cannot get any coordinates when I populate the layout with views, which happens in `onStart` method of my activity. In particular, I tried every recipe mentioned in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619693/getting-views-coordinates-relative-to-the-root-layout) but didn't succeed; all these methods return just zeros.

Nevertheless, if I repeat the calculation later (i. e. in a button handler), they do calculate the proper position.

So my assumption is that `onStart` is not a good place to calculate positions because something is not ready yet. But which place would be better? According to [the docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html), `onStart` is the last call before the activity is displayed to the user. I tried moving my math into `onResume` but that didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can be sure that views have valid coordinates this way:

```
parentView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        // really important! elsewhere this method will be called continously
        parentView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

        // do your job
    }
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot!