# Rendering Bitmap based on Views position in parent

Tags: android, scale, android-canvas, android-view, android-bitmap

I'm trying to make a simple image editor. At the beginning I've thought that it'll be a good idea to simply save view state as Bitmap but, as it turned out, there is a wide range of screen resolutions and that leads to huge quality (and memory usage) fluctuations.

Now I'm trying to make a module that renders views state translated to desired resolution.

In the code below I'm trying to recreate current state of the views in canvas:

```
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.test_1_1);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, parentView.getMeasuredWidth(), parentView.getMeasuredHeight(), true);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    for (View rootView : addedViews) {
        ImageView imageView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.sticker);

        float[] viewPosition = new float[2];
        transformToAncestor(viewPosition, parentView, imageView);

        Bitmap originalBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        Matrix adjustMatrix = new Matrix();
        adjustMatrix.postTranslate(viewPosition[0], viewPosition[1]);
        adjustMatrix.postScale(
                rootView.getScaleX(),
                rootView.getScaleY(),
                rootView.getWidth() / 2,
                rootView.getHeight() / 2);
        adjustMatrix.postRotate(rootView.getRotation(),
                rootView.getWidth() / 2,
                rootView.getHeight() / 2);

        canvas.drawBitmap(originalBitmap, adjustMatrix, paint);
    }
```

`transformToAncestor` function is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36764422).

```
public static void transformToAncestor(float[] point, final View ancestor, final View descendant) {
    final float scrollX = descendant.getScrollX();
    final float scrollY = descendant.getScrollY();
    final float left = descendant.getLeft();
    final float top = descendant.getTop();
    final float px = descendant.getPivotX();
    final float py = descendant.getPivotY();
    final float tx = descendant.getTranslationX();
    final float ty = descendant.getTranslationY();
    final float sx = descendant.getScaleX();
    final float sy = descendant.getScaleY();

    point[0] = left + px + (point[0] - px) * sx + tx - scrollX;
    point[1] = top + py + (point[1] - py) * sy + ty - scrollY;

    ViewParent parent = descendant.getParent();
    if (descendant != ancestor && parent != ancestor && parent instanceof View) {
        transformToAncestor(point, ancestor, (View) parent);
    }
}
```

(author wrote a note that his function does not support rotation, but there's not much rotation in my example so I don't think that important for now).

**My problem is:**

[image: Image generated via drawing views state]
[image: Image generated via views to image function]

First image is generated via saving the parent view state. Second one is generated by translating views position, rotation and scale onto canvas. 
As you can see, on the canvas, not scaled stickers are positioned properly, but scaled are incorrectly positioned.

How to position those scaled views properly?

Comment: what do you need `transformToAncestor` method at all? is your goal to create some kind of layers (in your case drawn with white stars) - each layer scaled, translated and possibly rotated?

Comment: I'm using this method to translate each star's position and then I'm scaling and rotating it. Is there a better way to do this?
My goal is to render image based on views position, layers are not neccesary.

Comment: i dont get it: you are using both `ImageView`s and `Canvas#drawBitmap`, what for? just use a custom view and `Canvas#drawBitmap` and you will control everything with almost no extra logic

Comment: like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/21657145/2252830 for example

Comment: User is editing image via manipulating ImageViews on the screen. After user is done, I want to recreate effect on Canvas to get a possibility to control output image resolution.
In the code I provided I'm looping through views added to editor (stars) and I'm trying to place actual Bitmaps on canvas.

Comment: how is he manipulating `ImageView`s? why not to manipulate `Bitmap`s itself? did you see the link i posted in my previous comment?

Comment: Yes, I saw the link. My editor is based on [this library](https://github.com/burhanrashid52/PhotoEditor). It's default way to save an edited image is to save state of the parent. I want to make the render function that only recreates views state. That will allow me to fully control output image resolution.

Comment: personally i would fork that library and remove any `ImageView`s that it uses and replace with primitive, low level `Bitmap`s - if you want to use them both you will never get pixel perfect solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix the issue myself.
It turned out my solution was nearly OK but I did not took into consideration that my manipulation of a matrix **does change the arrangement of the original points**, so my

```
rootView.getWidth() / 2,
rootView.getHeight() / 2
```

is no longer applicable as a center of the view after calling `Matrix.postScale` or `Matrix.postRotation`.

I wanted to:

- *apply scale* with pivot on top left corner,
- *apply rotation* with pivot on the center of the view.

Given the assumptions, here's the working code:

```
    // setup variables for sizing and transformation
    float position[] = new float[2];
    transformToAncestor(position, rootView, imageView);
    float desiredRotation = imageView.getRotation();
    float sizeDeltaX = imageView.getMeasuredWidth() / (float) imageBitmap.getWidth();
    float sizeDeltaY = imageView.getMeasuredHeight() / (float) imageBitmap.getHeight();
    float desiredScaleX = imageView.getScaleX() * sizeDeltaX * scaleX;
    float desiredScaleY = imageView.getScaleY() * sizeDeltaY * scaleY;
    float imageViewWidth = imageView.getMeasuredWidth() * imageView.getScaleX();
    float imageViewHeight = imageView.getMeasuredHeight() * imageView.getScaleY();

    float rootViewWidth = rootView.getMeasuredWidth();
    float rootViewHeight = rootView.getMeasuredHeight();
    float percentXPos = position[0] / rootViewWidth;
    float percentYPos = position[1] / rootViewHeight;
    float percentXCenterPos = (position[0] + imageViewWidth/2)
            / rootViewWidth;
    float percentYCenterPos = (position[1] + imageViewHeight/2)
            / rootViewHeight;

    float desiredPositionX = background.getWidth() * percentXPos;
    float desiredPositionY = background.getHeight() * percentYPos;
    float desiredCenterX = background.getWidth() * percentXCenterPos;
    float desiredCenterY = background.getHeight() * percentYCenterPos;

    // apply above variables to matrix
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    float[] points = new float[2];
    matrix.postTranslate(
            desiredPositionX,
            desiredPositionY);

    matrix.mapPoints(points);
    matrix.postScale(
            desiredScaleX,
            desiredScaleY,
            points[0],
            points[1]);

    matrix.postRotate(
            desiredRotation,
            desiredCenterX,
            desiredCenterY);

    // apply matrix to bitmap, then draw it on canvas
    canvas.drawBitmap(imageBitmap, matrix, paint);
```

As you can see, the `mapPoints` method was the answer for my question - it simply returns points ***after*** tranformation.